# Importing schema to new or different tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, import

Is there a convenient way to import a schema into Oracle 11gR2 using a single new or different tablespace than where the data originated?

As an example, I have exported BLOG_DATA from OLDDB, where all user data is stored in the USERS tablespace.

On NEWDB, I would like to import the BLOG_DATA schema, but store the user objects in the BLOG_DATA tablespace, created specifically for this user.

I have created the BLOG_DATA user, created the BLOG_DATA tablespace and set it as the default tablespace for that user and added an appropriate unlimited quota.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE blog_data DATAFILE SIZE 1G;

CREATE USER blog_data IDENTIFIED BY secretpassword DEFAULT TABLESPACE blog_data QUOTA UNLIMITED ON blog_data;

GRANT connect,resource TO blog_data
```

The schema was exported from OLDDB with something like

```
exp blog_data/secretpassword@OLDDB file=blog_data.dmp
```

**After reading Phil's excellent answer below, I found myself wondering**:

Since data has no other place to go than the default tablespace - the only tablespace the user has a quota on - will this effectively force imp to put all user objects in that default tablespace?

```
imp blog_data/secretpassword@NEWDB file=blog_data.dmp
```

Would this then place the entire blog_data schema in the blog_data tablespace on NEWDB? Is there any reason why this wouldn't work or that I would run into problems with certain objects etc?

**update:**

I did a quick test and found this to be the case. `Imp` places objects in the default tablespace for that user, provided it can't place it in the original tablespace (eg. the tablespace does not exist). Full explanation: http://www.dolicapax.org/?p=57

Still, I suppose that using Data Pump like Phil suggests might be the preferred option.

Comment: Was it exported using the legacy `exp` utility or with `expdp` (data pump)?

Comment: In the example it was exported with the conventional exp utility, as shown above. I suppose one could just as easily use expdp and pick up the file from the old db server, would that make the transition to a new tablespace any easier?

Comment: I've covered both in my answer. Use data pump - it's easier to perform this task

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not actually possible to specify a different tablespace when importing using the oracle `imp` utility. However, as a workaround, you can pre-create the tables by doing a `ROWS=N` import into the `USERS` tablespace, then `alter table mytable move tablespace BLOG_DATA;` for each table to move them to the new tablespace, then do the import again with the `IGNORE=Y` parameter to ignore the table creation errors and import all of the data.

If the data was exported using Data Pump (`expdp`), (as an aside, everyone should be using this these days, rather than the old legacy `exp`/`imp` utilities) you can easily import into another tablespace using the `REMAP_TABLESPACE` parameter.

eg:

```
impdp scott/tiger@ZOMG file=blog_data.dmp directory=mydir remap_tablespace=USERS:BLOG_DATA
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Phil. I was wondering: If the user being imported to exclusively has a quota on the default tablespace, will that force imp to place all  imported objects in that default tablespace regardless of the layout on the source of the data?

Comment: I'm working on something similar but it's a whole DB migration using expdp/impdp because I want our QA env to match production.
If I use remap_tablespace it would remap every schema into another single tablespace, however I think I can run the impdp command once per schema and using remap_tablespace. This should achieve the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the steps as below mentioned:-

- Export the user
- Perform import using the command
  `imp system/manager file=export.dmp indexfile=newfile.sql`
  This will import the data and save all definitions into `newfile.sql`.
- Drop necessary objects.
- Run the script `newfile.sql` after altering the tablespaces.
- Import from the backup for the necessary objects.