# Sql developer how to copy to another tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

When copying database using SQL Developer it complaints that the source tablespace does not exist on destination database.

How can I copy schema and data from Database `A` tablespace `t1` into Database `B` tablespace `t2`?

Note: I do not wish to use impdp.

Comment: Also check this out.http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25855/importing-schema-to-new-or-different-tablespace

Comment: Both links using impdp not sqldeveloper JDBC copy.

Comment: The difference in functionality is that I do not have admin access, the DB machine is remote, and I do not have oracle client installed locally. I'm working over JDBC link.

Comment: I just tried this and it works A-OK. I copied objects in db A to db B and db B doesn't have the same tablespace. in fact, the CREATE TABLE commands we generate do not even include the tablespace. Are you using Tools > Database Copy?

Comment: Yes I'm using Tools > DB Copy. Sql dev seems to require destination tablespace to have same name. I'm using sql dev 3.1. I'll try with 4.1 aswell. It may be a bit more intelligent.

Comment: not an issue in latest version, 3.1 is pretty old so it's possible it worked that way about 5 or 6 years ago